# Battery won't charge and BSOD: DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE

Tags: windows-7, bsod, battery, dell-vostro

I have a Dell Vostro 1510 running Windows 7.

Today when I pulled my machine out of it's bag and plugged it in, the little battery light on the side blinked constantly instead of staying solid, and Windows showed a message that the battery was not charging. The battery is 3.5 years old, but it can still hold the machine in standby overnight, so I don't know why it won't charge anymore.

After I have had the machine on for a while (20 minutes the first time, 40 minutes the second time), it shows a blue screen of death with the message DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE and reboots.

I can deal with the battery being dead, but not with blue screens of death. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Edit: Potentially relevant, this started happening after an OS update was automatically installed on Friday and Windows started nagging to reboot. The first BSOD was before the reboot; the update made a lot of registry changes when the machine came up, and the second BSOD was 40 minutes later.

Edit2: It seems that having an SDCard mounted was messing things up. I took it out and now there's no more BSOD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The battery is 3.5 years old --- I don't know why it won't charge anymore."

Notebook batteries are indented to be replaced yearly (approximately).  If you're has lasted 3.5 years, it's probably time to consider a replacement, and would be me first guess as to what's wrong.

Usually the blinking battery LED mean the battery had failed.  [Here's](http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/kcs/document?c=us&l=en&s=gen&docid=DSN_12FCCAA558727884E0401E0A55172D6B&isLegacy=true) a list of Dell's battery indicator states and what they mean.

Remove the battery and just run of AC, if it's stable, it's probably the battery.

To test this anther way, why not use Windows' System Restore to go back to a point before you installed the suspect updates, and see if it runs as expected or not?

The only other thing I would suggest is to hit Dell's site and get the latest BIOS and drivers for the machine, as the updates may have contained a driver that's not playing nicely.

Comment: Yearly replacement seems really excessive. The battery started off with a 4 hour life, and had only dropped by 30 or 45 minutes after the first year. It could run for almost an hour when it stopped recharging; that's not been my experience with laptop batteries that died naturally in the past. I haven't owned a Dell previously, so my conspiracy theory is that they've got hardware circuit blocking charging because battery capacity dropped below some arbitrary limit.

Comment: @JamesGecko They usually only give you a one year battery warranty for a reason. ;)  Perhaps just one/some of the cells in the battery died.. that may be where the proposed capacity limit is coming from(?).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error some days ago, Windows 7 shows a message about "Connected but not charging" an effectively it was not charging the battery, I follow the steps on this blog and it solved the problem.

http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/plugged-in-not-charging-windows-7-solution/

- Disconnect AC
- Shutdown
- Remove battery
- Connect AC
- Startup
- Under the Batteries category, right-click all of the Microsoft ACPI Compliant Control Method Battery listings, and select Uninstall (it’s ok if you only have 1).
- Shutdown
- Disconnect AC
- Insert battery
- Connect AC
- Startup

Hope it helps with your issue.